# Hiding custom fields in copy past option

Tags: acumatica

How to hide a field while copy and past. The field is part of the extension of the sales order.DAC.

I have tried  [PXCopyPasteHiddenFields(typeof(PSSOOrderExtNV.usrIsInHandsDate))] and I am getting the following compilation error.

Error    CS0592    Attribute 'PXCopyPasteHiddenFields' is not valid on this declaration type. It is only valid on 'class, field' declarations.

I have tried to Override the method CopyPasteGetScript I did not get the desired result.

```
public delegate void CopyPasteGetScriptDelegate(Boolean isImportSimple, List<Command> script, List<Container> containers);
    [PXOverride]
    public void CopyPasteGetScript(Boolean isImportSimple, List<Command> script, List<Container> containers, CopyPasteGetScriptDelegate baseMethod)
    {
        baseMethod(isImportSimple, script, containers);
        SOOrder order = Base.Document.Current;
        if(Base.Document.Cache.GetStatus(order) == PXEntryStatus.Inserted)
        {
            PSSOOrderExtNV extn = PXCache<SOOrder>.GetExtension<PSSOOrderExtNV>(order);
            extn.UsrHoldUntil = null;
            extn.UsrReadyforProductionapproval = null;
            extn.UsrReadyForProduction = null;
            extn.UsrIsOrdered = null;
            extn.UsrIsAllocated = null;
            extn.UsrEmbPaperReceived = null;
            extn.UsrEmbGoodsReceived = null;
            extn.UsrWorksheetPrinted = null;
            extn.UsrGoodsOnCarts = null;
            Base.Document.Update(order);
        }
    }
```

**Update**

I have modified the code as bellow in graph extension of SOOrderEntry. It is not giving error while compiling, but it is copying the values to new order.

```
        [PXCopyPasteHiddenFields(typeof(SOOrder.cancelled), typeof(SOOrder.preAuthTranNumber), typeof(SOOrder.ownerID), typeof(SOOrder.workgroupID), 
                             typeof(PSSOOrderExtNV.usrHoldUntil),typeof(PSSOOrderExtNV.usrReadyForProduction),typeof(PSSOOrderExtNV.usrReadyforProductionapproval),typeof(PSSOOrderExtNV.usrIsOrdered),
                             typeof(PSSOOrderExtNV.usrIsAllocated),typeof(PSSOOrderExtNV.usrEmbPaperReceived),typeof(PSSOOrderExtNV.usrEmbGoodsReceived),typeof(PSSOOrderExtNV.usrWorksheetPrinted),
                             typeof(PSSOOrderExtNV.usrGoodsOnCarts))]
    public PXSelect<SOOrder, Where<SOOrder.orderType, Equal<Current<SOOrder.orderType>>, And<SOOrder.orderNbr, Equal<Current<SOOrder.orderNbr>>>>> CurrentDocument;
```

Comment: Putting the attribute on a DataView is definitely an improvement. As for why fields are still copied, is PSSOOrderExtNV a direct extension on SOOrder declared as class PSSOOrderExtNV : PXCacheExtension<SOOrder> ?

Answer (score 0):

PXCopyPasteHiddenFields attribute typically decorates DataViews.

This example in Sales Order graph, hides the SOLine.Completed field from the Transactions DataView:

```
[PXViewName(Messages.SOLine)]
[PXImport(typeof(SOOrder))]
[PXCopyPasteHiddenFields(typeof(SOLine.completed))]
public PXOrderedSelect<SOOrder, SOLine,
    Where<SOLine.orderType, Equal<Current<SOOrder.orderType>>,
        And<SOLine.orderNbr, Equal<Current<SOOrder.orderNbr>>>>,
    OrderBy<Asc<SOLine.orderType, Asc<SOLine.orderNbr, Asc<SOLine.sortOrder, Asc<SOLine.lineNbr>>>>>> Transactions;
```

Comment: It is not working for extension dac. I have tried with the following and gave error while compiling

[PXCopyPasteHiddenFields(typeof(PSSOOrderExtNV.usrIsInHandsDate))] .

Comment: A problem I have with your question is that I can't tell if you put the attribute in the right place and the error message is stating you didn't. Can you add more code to understand the context to your question? You could have placed the attribute anywhere as far as I know and it will give you that same error so I need to confirm where it is located exactly.

Comment: > It is not working for extension dac.
- If you meant you placed the attribute on/in a DAC then that's not good, the point of my answer is you need to place the attribute on a DataView not on/in a DAC.